# Hasura lookup another table query on insert graphql

Tags: sql, graphql, lookup, hasura

I am imported some data to Author table (id, old_author_id, name)

I am wondering is it possible on insert of a book with old author id supplied get 'new' author_id, as shown below:

```
mutation InsertBook {
  insert_book_one(object: {title: "", old_author_id: "ST1M", author_id: ??? })
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you describe your data structures more? What is the structure of `book` table? How it is related to Author table? Are those tables related on Postgreslq level through foreign keys? Are there relationships defined on hasura level?